# How to run ThingsBoard from the public IP address of my AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, networking, ip-address, thingsboard

I am running a Ubuntu instance in EC2 AWS, I have installed ThingsBoard on Ubuntu following the documentation of ThingsBoard but to run the ThingsBoard platform, I am supposed to do it through the localhost address but I can't as I am connecting to the instance through SSH.

I have the public address of the instance and I want to run the ThingsBoard platform through that public IP address.

Could you please explain to me how can I open ThingsBoard from the public IP address of the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow this manual ?
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=aws-sqs

According to the documentation, after installing all packages and configuration, you can connect to the web UI on port 8080.

So you can connect to your instance through the public IP on port 8080, after adding the port to the inbound rules of your instance security group

Comment: Thanks for your response, well I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: The only thing I didn't understand my friend that how can I access to localhost of the ubuntu through the public IP address of the instance because in the documentation they said you have to open http://localhost:8080/ in the web UI to run Thingsboard

Comment: You can do it with a reverse proxy like nginx, or just follow the documentation, install HAProxy and configure an SSL certificate to connect through HTTPS with the public IP.

Comment: It's been a long time, so hopefully, your problem has been solved. In case, someone else is looking for it, give a simple solution. On the browser write the 'EC2 Public IPv DNS' (i.e. ec2.<your_elastic_IP.us-east-1.compute.amazaonaws.com>  something like that), then ':8080', You should see the Thingsboard login page. You can change the default port to other in '/etc/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml' file.